# Loop inside the loop

Tags: wp-query, loop

I'm working on a project where I need display 2 post from one category and also I need to put another loop between this post post to display random list of post from other category. Easiest way to do so is to create 3 queries, but when I created 2 queries for one category, but here I got problem one loop breaks and display both posts, second works fine. I used offset parameter for second query but it doesn't work.

```
<?php

        $first_query_args = array(
          'category_name' => 'first-category',
          'tag' => 'special-tag',
          'post_per_page' => 1,
        );

        $first_query = new WP_Query( $first_query_args );

        if ( $first_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $first_query->have_posts() ) : $first_query->the_post();

        // First query stuff goes here

        endwhile; endif;

        wp_reset_query(); 

        // Query for Random posts
        $query_for_random_args = array(
            'category_name' => 'cat-for-rand',
            'post_per_page' => 3,
            'orderby' => 'rand',
        );

        $query_for_random = new WP_Query( $query_for_random_args );

        if ( $query_for_random->have_posts() ) :
    ?>

        <ul>

        <?php while ( $query_for_random->have_posts() ) : $query_for_random->the_post(); ?>

            <li>
                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'list-image' ); ?></a>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" ><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            </li>

        <?php } endwhile; ?>

        </ul>

        <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>

    <?php


        $second_query_args = array(
          'category_name' => 'first-category',
          'tag' => 'special-tag',
          'offset' => 1,
          'post_per_page' => 1,
        );

        $second_query = new WP_Query( $second_query_args );

        if ( $second->have_posts() ) : while ( $second_query->have_posts() ) : $second_query->the_post();

        // Second query stuff goes here

        endwhile; endif;
?>
```

( This code What I use for those loops )

Any ideas how can I solve this problem? or how can I use 2 queries for similar task?

Cheers

George

Comment: Show the code you tried = best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `get_posts()` for your two *ad hoc* Loops. (Actually, you only need one *ad hoc* Loop, if you're modifying the main Loop so that only 2 posts are retrieved.) e.g.

```
\\ code modify main Loop to return only 2 posts goes here

$firstpost = true;

if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    \\ main Loop Post output goes here

    if ( $firstpost ) {

        $randomposts = get_posts( array( 'category' => $categoryid, 'numberposts' = $numberposts, 'orderby' => 'rand' );

        \\ Output ad-hod Loop content, e.g.
        ?>
        <ul>
        <?php
        foreach ( $randomposts as $randompost ) { ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $randompost->ID ); ?>"><?php echo $randompost->post_title; ?></a></li>
        <?php } ?>
        </ul>
    <?php }

   $firstpost = false;

// end the main Loop
endwhile; endif;
```

(Untested example code)

Comment: Hello Chip. Thanks for help. Yes I know that I can modify main loop with query_post. I thins situation I'm more interested if I can inset loop for random post like people use to insert google ads after first post or between posts

Comment: @Mamaduka yes, you can. That's what the `$randomposts = get_posts()` business is.

Comment: @Chip Bennett I tested your code example works great, but it outputs random post after each post from main loop. It great if you want place content after each post, in this example I only want to display random post after fist post

Comment: @Mamaduka I may have misread your OP. I assumed there would only be two posts in the main Loop. You could always add a variable, and only output the *ad hoc* Loop if the variable isn't set. Let me update my answer to give an example.

Comment: (Answer updated per above comment.)