# loop inside a loop : search for posts in the same category

Tags: loop, get-posts, categories

Could someone tell me how i could make this work? i have a loop, and i would like to create another loop to find the other posts from the same category : but this does not work :

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php /* How to display all other posts. */ ?>

                <?php

                $monid = the_ID();
                $cat = get_the_category($monid);  //this works
                $args = array( 'numberposts' => 5, 'offset'=> 1, 'category' => $cat );
                $myposts = get_posts( $args );
                var_dump($myposts); //this don't ?>
                <ul>

                </ul>
```

i found this topic [Loop inside the loop](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17604/loop-inside-the-loop) but it does not really work for me : any help?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it works like that :

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php
                    $cats = get_the_category();
                    $cat_obj = array_shift($cats);
                    var_dump($cat_obj);


                    $cat_id = (int) $cat_obj->cat_ID;

                    $qq = query_posts( 'cat=$cat_id&posts_per_page=1' );
                    //var_dump($qq);

                    foreach($qq as $q2){
                        var_dump($q2->post_content);
                    }

                    wp_reset_query();
                ?>
```

i hope this can help

Answer (score 1):

[`the_ID()`](http://queryposts.com/function/the_id/) prints the current post's ID. You need to use [`get_the_ID()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_the_id/) to return it.

Also, [`get_the_category`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category) returns an array of category objects - one foreach category term the post belongs to.

The 'category' attribute expects a category term ID. So you need to pick a category object, then obtain its ID:

```
  $cats = get_the_category();
  $cat_obj = array_shift($cats);
  $cat_id = (int) $cat_obj->cat_ID;
```

Then:

```
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 5, 'offset'=> 1, 'category' => $cat_id );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Stephen, so cat_id works, but `$myposts = get_posts( $args );` does not work: it returns an empty array ... Do know why?